# Storybook - Auto documenting react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, storybook

I'm trying to write a story for some react hooks on a project I'm writing, here's the hook, it's quite simple:

```
export function useHass(): HassContextProps {
  const context = useContext(HassContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useHass must be used within a HassProvider");
  }
  return context;
}
```

And the typescript definition for HassContextProps is:

```
export interface HassContextProps {
  connection: Connection | null;
  setConnection: (connection: Connection) => void;
  getEntity: (entity: string) => HassEntity;
  getAllEntities: () => HassEntities;
  callService: ({
    domain,
    service,
    serviceData,
    target,
  }: CallServiceArgs) => void;
  getStates: () => Promise<HassEntity[] | null>;
  getServices: () => Promise<HassServices | null>;
  getConfig: () => Promise<HassConfig | null>;
  getUser: () => Promise<HassUser | null>;
  ready: boolean;
  lastUpdated: Date;
}
```

My question is, what's the best way to generate a story for the hook, to outline the arguments hooks take, and the return value of the hook or is this all supposed to be manual? The ArgsTable works great for components, but not so much for hooks

Comment: Storybook is intended to be used for developing UI components. React hooks are not a UI component, so I suspect Storybook might not be the best tool for the job testing your custom React hooks.

Comment: I'm using storybook for all the components i have, but i also provide hooks, just thought it would be able to, that's okay i will just provide manual examples for the hooks